# getHeight() isn't returning correct value -using ViewTreeObserver- at first run

Tags: android

In `MainActivity` you click on a camera button, take a picture and then the image is shown on a `PreviewActivity` and then I should get the Width and Height of the `imageView`.

I tried to show a `log` message showing the height value when I touch the screen now the height value is corrected; so I think the problem is that the `imageView` isn't being laid out probably at first or something. "it got the height value before everything is laid right..", even though I'm using *`getViewTreeObserver()`*.

```
    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = mImageView.getViewTreeObserver();
    if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                mImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                setImage(mCurrentPhotoPath, selectedImageUri);
            }
        });
    }
```

---

**Edit:** I *figured out* that the problem is  that the height value is taller than it acually is; because when opening the *Camera app*, the ***statusBar*** is hidden and it gets shown back again on `PreviewActivity`, but the height of the imageView is measured before ***statusBar*** is back up again, which causes the problem and causes the Height to be taller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the Only way I was able to fix this problem is; if we got the image from the Camera (and if opened from `MainActivity`) then get the height and width after a little delay, so that everything is laid out probably.

```
//--             Get image path from previous activity
        mCurrentPhotoPath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
        selectedImageUri = getIntent().getData();

        helper.setImage(mCurrentPhotoPath, selectedImageUri); //set image to imageView


        if (cameraOpenedFromMainActivity) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //method to get height and width and do stuff
                }
            }, 500); //increase until everything is fine

        }else {
            ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = mImageView.getViewTreeObserver();
            if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
                viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        mImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                        //method to get height and width and do stuff
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        //--
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try get the width in post method like:

```
mImageView.post(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mHeight = mImageView.getHeight(); //height is ready
    }
});
```

As I know, runnable task in post will be executed after view's measure and layout.